# How to load a list of different components dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I know how to dynamically load **a** component, by using the import() method

```
const {TitleComponent} = await import('./title/title.component');
this.itemViewContainer.createComponent(TitleComponent);
```

Now I want to dynamically load a list of **different** components. I did the following

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.componentList.length; i++)
{
   let componentPath = this.componentList[i];
   let importedComponent = await import(componentPath);
   this.itemViewContainer.createComponent(importedComponent);
}
```

but it's breaking. I keep getting the error "cannot find module", on the line below.

```
let importedComponent = await import(componentPath);
```

if I change that line back to, say

```
const {TitleComponent} = await import(componentPath);
```

or

```
const {AddressComponent} = await import(componentPath);
```

Then, it works fine.

`TitleComponent` & `AddressComponent` are defined and exported Components. While `importedComponent` is just a variable.

How do I resolve this issue ?

Thanks for the assist

Comment: The problem is probably that webpack cannot find those components anymore. You can try to add those components to the ‘files’ section of tsconfig.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import yeah that's probably it. A few things to keep in mind `import()` is special -- it's not a function. It's function-like syntax. The usual idea of passing it arguments (if I can pass a string literal, I must be able to pass a variable etc.) doesn't _necessarily_ apply here.  Bundlers (webpack, rollup) will have their own rules on how they can process such a statement to resolve the proper chunks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is very much possible. Thought the way of doing it, is a good bit different from the step I took originally.

I will leave [this link](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/12/08/angular-dynamic-components) to a post explains how.

And also [this link](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-angular-dynamic-components-example) to the repository.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future.

Comment: Gotcha! Now I know. Thank